# Доступ к данным в другом классе

Tags: c++, полиморфизм

Добрый день! Вопрос по ООП на С++
 (отредактировал, убрал наследование)

Столкнулся с такой проблемой: есть класс Bank, и есть класс  Сlient, который содержит личные данные. В Bank есть вектор, который содержит объекты класса Client (проще говоря, содержит объекты, каждый из которых конкретный клиент).

И есть задача: в Bank написать функцию print() , *которая распечатывала бы данные всех клиентов, которые содержатся в векторе*. Только как это сделать правильно? Первая мысль была создать в Client функцию, которая возвращала бы все данные ( или несколько функций), и таким образом передать это в print().

**Но это решение не совсем верное**: получается, я раскрываю данные конкретных клиентов. Как сделать так, чтобы не создавать такую функцию?
спасибо!!

```
#include <iostream>
#include <time.h>
#include <vector>
#include <string>

using std::vector;
using std::string;
using std::cout;
using std::endl;

//--------class--------
class Client  {
public:
    //constructor
    Client(string name, int ID)  {
        this->ID = ID;
        this->name = name;
    }
    //function that returns ID of client
    int return_ID() {
        return ID;
    }

    //function that returns name of client
    string return_name() {
        return name;
    }

private:
    int ID;
    string name;
};

//---------------------------------------
class Bank {

private:

    //vector of clients
    vector<Client*> clients;


public:
    //function for adding clients to vector
    void addclientd(Client* client) {
        clients.push_back(client);
    }

    //function for printing data of clients
    void print() {
        for (int i = 0; i < clients.size(); i++) {
            cout << "ID is " << clients[i]->return_ID() << "   ";
            cout << "Name is " << clients[i]->return_name() << endl;
        }
    }

};




//---------------------------------
int main() {


    Client Ivanov("Ivanov", 3234);
    Client Somebody("Somebody", 2345);
    Bank bank;
    bank.addclientd(&Ivanov);
    bank.addclientd(&Somebody);

    bank.print();

    system("pause");
    return 0;

}
```

Comment: "класс Bank, от которого наследует класс Сlient" - о-о-о, опять! Клиент не может наследовать от банка, так как он не является банком.

Comment: советую создать [mcve]

Comment: логично. Хотя если Client не наследует от Bank' я не могу создать вектор клиентов и полиморфизм.. что-то я запутался

Comment: @Vintazh, в любом случае приложите код чтобы Вас могли лучше понять

Comment: добавил код и изменил  вопрос.

Answer (score 0):

Организуйте у класса `Client` метод `print()` который будет выводить данные экземпляра.

А у банка аналогично метод `print()` должен в цикле перебирать вектор клиентов и вызывать вышеуказанный метод клиента.

И прочитайте про [стиль написания кода,](https://m.habrahabr.ru/post/172091/) будет полезно.